# Qualified S/MIME signature with Thunderbird

Tags: thunderbird, smartcard, digital-signature

Is it possible to send S/MIME digitally signed email with Mozilla Thunderbird using qualified digital signing smart card? How?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, if your card reader has a compatible PKCS#11 module.

On Thunderbird, go to *Tools → Account Settings*, and under your mail account select *Security*. Click *Security Devices* and you will see a list all loaded modules and devices. Click *Load* and select the PKCS#11 module file for your card reader. (On Windows, it's a `.dll` file; on Linux, `.so`.)

- The same window can be reached through *Tools → Options → Advanced → Certificates → Security Devices*.
- The location of PKCS#11 modules is not standardized (although there are [attempts to do so](http://wiki.cacert.org/Pkcs11TaskForce)), so you may need to do some searching. (On Windows, two likely locations are the card reader software directory, and `%SystemRoot%\System32`.) CAcert has [a list of common locations](http://wiki.cacert.org/Pkcs11TaskForce). You could also use the "auto-detect library" capability in TrueCrypt or FreeOTFE, then copy the resulting path into Thunderbird.

Close *Security Devices* and click *View Certificates*, and you should see certificates contained in the smartcard. Close the window and use the two *Select...* buttons to choose encryption and signing certificate(s).